# Why is it necessary to wrap arguments to React functional components in braces?

Tags: reactjs

I just spent an embarassingly long amount of time trying to track down very weird behavior in my React components and figuring out what was going on.

Turns out that I had two components that look like this:

```
// class component
export class ParentComponent extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            {...some stuff}
            <AnotherComponent someBoolean={true} />
        );
    }
}

// functional component
export const AnotherComponent = (someBoolean) => (
    <div>
        <!-- Some more HTML here -->
    </div>
);
```

I needed to do some conditional formatting on the result of `someBoolean` and could not, for the life of me, figure out what was going wrong. Therefore, I just set `someBoolean` to `true` and rendered what the result of that was in `AnotherComponent`. The results were bizarre and didn't make any sense.

Long story short: I finally figured out what was going on.  I needed to wrap the arguments of `AnotherComponent` with braces such that they look like this:

```
export const AnotherComponent = ({someBoolean}) => (
    <div>
        <!-- Some more HTML here -->
    </div>
);
```

Finally, everything worked.  My question is: why?  Why is this needed and what does the wrapping of the braces do?  I can't find anything on it out there and none of the React docs seem to mention this at all.

Comment: For the `AnotherComponent`, props gets passed in as an argument which is an object that will have a property called `someBoolean` so by adding braces around it, you are using ES7 destructuring of an object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first argument for a functional component is it's props. So you are just [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) `someBoolean` from the props object. You could also do something like this:

```js
export const AnotherComponent = (props) => (
  <div>{props.someBoolean}</div>
);
```

or

```js
export const AnotherComponent = (props) => {
  const {someBoolean} = props;
  return (
    <div>{someBoolean}</div>
  );
};
```

The way you found it works is just shortening the syntax into one step.